# Placeholder text color differs depending on browser

Tags: html

Font text color show white in crome and black in mozilla fire here is my 
code

```css
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-780"><input type="text" name="text-780" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required Name-colorclass" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name"></span>
```

Comment: Here is my url link https://www.futurexeed.com/

Comment: I tested this in both firefox and chrome, can't seem to reproduce your issue. It's white in both for me. What versions are you using?

Comment: no sir in crome its white but in mox is black i want white in both

Comment: mox ? is that firefox?

Comment: sir in mozila firebox is  showing black i want white

Comment: i am using 65.0  version

Answer (score 3):

That's because you didn't set color to the placeholder itself, Chrome smartly change the color of the placeholder (and if you want to be specific you can use `::placeholder` to change it back) Firefox don't do it so you have to be specific

Here's how to do it with the `::placeholder` pseudo-class

```css
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass {
    color: #fff;
}

input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass::placeholder,
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass::-moz-placeholder,
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass:-moz-placeholder,
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass::-webkit-placeholder,
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-validates-as-required.Name-colorclass:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-780"><input type="text" name="text-780" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required Name-colorclass" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name"></span>
```

Comment: @user10710652 the little green check bellow the up/down vote buttons mate ;D

Comment: in area feild is not working:<textarea name="textarea-562" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

Comment: textarea.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea::placeholder {
    color: #ffff !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

Comment: try with the vendor prefix, like this : `::-moz-placeholder`